# If a sequence of random variables converges to both $X$ and $Y$ almost surely, then $X$ and $Y$ have the same distribution

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence

Show that if .${X_n}\mathop  \to \limits^{a.s} {\rm{ }}X$. and ${X_n}\mathop  \to \limits^{a.s} {\rm{ }}Y$ ,then X and Y have the same distribution.

Proof Let   $A = \{ \omega  \in \Omega :X(\omega ) = Y(\omega )\} $ , P(A)=1 For $x \in R$

$(X \le x)$$ = [(X \le x) \cap A] \cup [(X \le x) \cap {A^c}]$
            $ = [(X(\omega ) \le x) \cap X(\omega ) = Y(\omega )] \cup [(X \le x) \cap X(\omega ) \ne Y(\omega )]$

$P(X \le x)$$ = P[(X(\omega ) \le x) \cap X(\omega ) = Y(\omega )] + P[(X \le x) \cap X(\omega ) \ne Y(\omega )]$

$ = P[(X(\omega ) \le x) \cap X(\omega ) = Y(\omega )]$

$ = P[(Y(\omega ) \le x) \cap X(\omega ) = Y(\omega )]$

$ = P[(Y(\omega ) \le x)]$

$= P[Y \le x]$

Then X and Y have the same distribution.

This idea it True or False. Thank

Comment: @Bungo You may want to post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Looks OK to me. You may want to clarify that $P[(Y \leq x) \cap (X = Y)] = P[Y \leq x]$ by the same reasoning you used a few lines earlier:
$$P[(Y \leq x) \cap (X = Y)] = P[(Y \leq x) \cap (X = Y)] + P[(Y \leq x) \cap (X \neq Y)]$$
This equality holds because the second term on the right hand side is zero, since $\{(Y \leq X) \cap (X \neq Y)\}$ is a subset of the zero-probability event $\{X \neq Y\}$. Then use
$$P[(Y \leq x) \cap (X = Y)] + P[(Y \leq x) \cap (X \neq Y)] = P(Y \leq x)$$